# Not able to read the input of a String

Tags: java, string

I'm doing a calculator, in which is asked to the user to put two numbers, and then an aritmethical operator, so a set of IFs will understand what operator it is and do the operation required:

```
public class Calc {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("First number: ");
double num1 = input.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Second number: ");
double num2 = input.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Artithemtical operator(-, +, :, x): ");
String segn = input.nextLine();


if(segn == "+" ) {
System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num1 + num2));
}
else if(segn == "-") {
System.out.println(num1 + " - " + num2 + " = " + (num1 - num2));
}
else if(segn == "x") {
System.out.println(num1 + " x " + num2 + " = " + (num1 * num2));
}
else if(segn == ":") {
   System.out.println(num1 + " : " + num2 + " = " + (num1 / num2));
}


   }
}
```

as you can see if the input is a specific operator it will perform the specific task.
It works well, it makes you put the two numbers, the operator but then it does nothing, what shall I do?

Comment: `==` checks for reference identity between objects, which is not what you want here. `segn.equals("x")` is right, `segn == "x"` won't get it done.

Answer (score 0):

String comparison should be perfomed with `equals()` method.

`==` compares your objects links in a heap to each other. And in your case they will be different. Because you have two completely different strings (in terms of java memory model) in each `if` statement.

One of that is the string that you're reading from input, and another one is the string which you're created inline, for example your `"+"` sign.

It is two different objects in memory, and when you're trying to compare links to them - they will be different.

Correct version of your class:

```
public class Calc {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("First number: ");
    double num1 = input.nextDouble();
    input.nextLine(); //bug fix
    System.out.print("Second number: ");
    double num2 = input.nextDouble();
    input.nextLine(); //bug fix
    System.out.print("Artithemtical operator(-, +, :, x): ");
    String segn = input.nextLine();

    if (segn.equals("+")) {
      System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num1 + num2));
    } else if (segn.equals("-")) {
      System.out.println(num1 + " - " + num2 + " = " + (num1 - num2));
    } else if (segn.equals("x")) {
      System.out.println(num1 + " x " + num2 + " = " + (num1 * num2));
    } else if (segn.equals(":")) {
      System.out.println(num1 + " : " + num2 + " = " + (num1 / num2));
    }
  }
}
```

And you have a small bug inside your class. It's related to using of `Scanner`. And your sign input is just ignored.
Please, take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo).